# When to split programs into two repositories?

Tags: coding-style, repository

If you have 2 applications that share a lot of code. What is the general guideline before splitting the 2 applications into two different repositories?

Say they share about 80% of code and forms etc. Is it a good idea to split them or keep them together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they share 80% of the same code, then yes, split them into three repositories:

- the common code becomes a library
- first application, including the library
- second application, including the library

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself

Comment: Thanks. Yeah that makes a lot of sense to approach it in this way.